# Adding validation in kendo datepicker results recusrive call

Tags: kendo-ui, datepicker, focus, kendo-asp.net-mvc, blur

I have a datepicker and validation in it's blur event. If validation fails I am showing a message to user and focus the datepicker again. But it becomes recursive.

Message appears all the time. User can't get of the loop unless she kills the page.

```js
(function() {
  $("#kendoDatePicker").kendoDatePicker();

  $("#kendoDatePicker").on("blur", function() {
    if ($(this).data("kendoDatePicker").value() > new Date()) {
      alert("Date cannot be greater than today. Please re-enter.");
      var datepicker = $(this).data("kendoDatePicker");
      datepicker.element.focus();
    }
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.2.913/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="demo-section k-content">
  <input id="kendoDatePicker" value="04/04/2017" style="width: 100%" />
</div>
```

Fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/Hd47F/312/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you said it yourself that you are focusing the datepicker again in the blur event. So, of course it will become recursive. You can put the validation logic inside the form submit event, instead of the datepicker's blur event, or do not focus into the datepicker after the validation.

By the way, you don't even need validation. You can set the maximum date of the datepicker to today's date so that the user can't even choose a date in the future. That will also make it more user-friendly.

Comment: Thanks for your input.

Can you please explain why it will become recursive. 

As my requirement is to show user a error/warning message and force her to enter correct date is there any other way I can achive this?

Comment: Because focusing on the input will trigger the validation again.